# How to filter by an expression when mocking a repository with Moq

Tags: c#, .net, testing, moq

I have a method in a repository that receives an `Expression` as a parameter and the result of the method are supposed to filter by that expression. The thing is that when I try to test this method, it doesn't give me the result filtered:

Service method I'm testing

```
public async Task<Response<IEnumerable<AirlineDto>>> GetAllAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var airlines = await _airlineRepository.GetAsync(x => x.Status); // call to the real repo
        ... // some logic
    }
    ... // exception handling
}
```

Method Setup, `MockAirlineRepository` is a mock of `AirlineRepository`

```
public MockAirlineRepository MockGetAll()
{
    Setup(x => x.GetAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Airline, bool>>>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(GetTestAirlines);
    return this;
}

private static IEnumerable<Airline> GetTestAirlines()
{
    var airlines = new List<Airline>
    {
        new()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "Test One",
            Status = true
        },
        new()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "Test Two",
            Status = true
        },
        new()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "Test Three",
            Status = false // notice that this Airline Status is false, so, 
                           // the count of the retrieved values should be 2
        }
    };
    return airlines;
}
```

Test

```
[Fact]
public void AirlineService_GetAll_ReturnsAirlines()
{
    //Arrange
    var mockAirlineRepo = new MockAirlineRepository().MockGetAll();
    var airlineService = new AirlineService(mockAirlineRepo.Object, _airlineMapper);

    //Act
    var result = airlineService.GetAllAsync().Result.Data;

    //Assert
    var airlineDtoList = result.ToList();
    Assert.NotEmpty(airlineDtoList);
    Assert.Equal(2, airlineDtoList.Count); // assert fails, because airlineDtoList.Count is 3
    mockAirlineRepo.VerifyGetAllAirlines(Times.Once());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the basics:

- **Dummy**: simple code that returns bogus data
- **Fake**: a working alternative which can take shortcuts
- **Stub**: custom logic with predefined data
- **Mock**: custom logic with expectations (interactive stub)
- **Shim**: custom logic at run-time (replace static with a delegate)
- **Spy**: interceptors to record calls

So, your mock is an interactive stub which means it can return different outputs based on the received input. In your `Setup` call you have made the following statement: *whatever I receive as a filter expression I should always return with the entire list*

If you want to apply the filter then change your setup

```
.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Airline, bool>>>()))
.ReturnsAsync(filter => GetTestAirlines.Where(filter));
```

Now if you assert on `airlineDtoList.Count` then it will return 2. But in this case you are not testing the `GetAllAsync` function rather than your mock.

So, I would rather spend more time testing the `// some logic`

---

You can also take advantage of `async`-`await` in your test

```
[Fact]
public Task AirlineService_GetAll_ReturnsAirlines()
{
    //Arrange
    var mockAirlineRepo = new MockAirlineRepository().MockGetAll();
    var airlineService = new AirlineService(mockAirlineRepo.Object, _airlineMapper);

    //Act
    var response = await airlineService.GetAllAsync();
    var result = response.Data;

    //Assert
    ...
}
```